# server can't run events on socket that reconected (Socket.io)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm a starter developer. I use socket.io for my app, which is based on a chat app.

I have a problem when the client disconnects accidentally (E.g. wi-fi on the PC disconnects). When wi-fi is connected again, the client enters the 'reconnect' event. After that, the connection is correctly reseted in the upper way (client to server) but won't work in the down way (server to client). After the re-connect my client will emit events that run on the server... but the server can't emit events that work on the client (the one that reconnected).

E.G: 
client side:
I have this button created when the user logs in that when clicked sends the 'ready' event to the server.

```
socket.on('login', function (data) {
    connected = true;
    $matchId=data.id
    var btn;
    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML= "Ready";
    btn.className = "readybtn";
    btn.id = "readyBtn";
    btn.onclick = function ready(){
        socket.emit('ready',{
            id: $matchId
        });
    };
    document.getElementById("dropdownDiv").appendChild(btn);
});
```

server side (extract of one of the multiple events i've designed).

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function(data){
        var matchIdx;
        for (var i = 0; i < srv.matches.length; i++) {
            if(srv.matches[i].matchId == data.id) matchIdx = i;//indexOf
        }
        socket.to(srv.matches[matchIdx].matchId).emit('new message',{
            username:socket.username,
            message: "I'm ready"
        });
    }
});
```

Therefore, as you can see the when some client clicks on the Ready button, a I'm ready message with the client's username appears to everybody in the room.

My problem comes here, after the reconnect event (from socket.io) if I test this, the message will be displayed on all the clients except for those that reconnected. Even if I switch off the wi-fi on a client and then click on the ready button, I will see the I'm Ready message in all the clients but the one that reconnected. This means, that after the reconnect, the client is able to trigger the 'ready' event of the server, but the server cannot establish the connection to the client, since the 'new message' event is not triggered in the reconnected client.

I've tried to emit directly to the client that reconnected, to check if it is related to the rooms, but it does not work either.

Can somebody tell me how to solve this? Refreshing is not an option..

Thanks in advance.

I attach the reconnect event:

```
socket.on('reconnect', function () {
    log("you were reconnected");
});
```

PS: Sorry for poor English and explanation, it is my first question.

Comment: Please provide us a code sample. The problem is not clear just from your question.

Comment: tldr: [mcve] ...